# Symfony 2 GET url parameters API

Tags: php, api, symfony

I ask an API which redirects on my website with this URL:

```
http://localhost/#!/Test?code=e5854f28a9bd2940734t58f91a333662
```

In my controller I would like to catch "code" parameter like this:

```
<?php
$request = $this->get('request');
if($request->query->get('code'))
    echo 'ok';
else
    echo 'not ok';
?>
```

But there's nothing on `$request->query`... I suppose it's because I have no route with this format, but how can I force or get it? Or do I have to create a route?

Answer (score 4):

Stuff after the hashbang is not processed by the server, so your `$request` object will be empty.

Hashbang routes should be handled by the client [Backbone.js, Angular.js, whatever], which should ask the server for proper [RESTful] resources, which will use regular URI schema.